# Parsing characters into an std::map<char,int> using boost::qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to parse a sequence of characters separated by a "," into an std::map<char,int> of pairs  where the key is the character and the value just the a count of parsed characters.
For example, if the input is

```
 a,b,c
```

The map should contain the pairs:

```
(a,1) , (b,2) , (c,3)
```

Here's the code I am using :

```
namespace myparser
{
    std::map<int, std::string> mapping;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
    int i = 0;

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::map<char,int>& v)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::phrase_parse;
        using qi::_1;
        using ascii::space;
        using phoenix::push_back;

        bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,

            //  Begin grammar
            (

               
                char_[v.insert(std::make_pair(_1,0)]
                    >> *(',' >> char_[v.insert(std::make_pair(_1,0)])
            )
            ,
            //  End grammar

            space);

        if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
            return false;
        return r;
    }
    //]
}
```

Then I try to print the pair in main like this:

```
int main() {
  std::string str;
    while (getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        std::map<char,int> v;
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = v.begin();
        if (myparser::parse_numbers(str.begin(), str.end(), v))
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
            std::cout << str << " Parses OK: " << std::endl;

        while (it != v.end())
        {
        // Accessing KEY from element pointed by it.
        std::string word = it->first;
        // Accessing VALUE from element pointed by it.
        int count = it->second;
        std::cout << word << " :: " << count << std::endl;
        // Increment the Iterator to point to next entry
        it++;
         }

            std::cout << "\n-------------------------\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner and I don't know how to fix this code . I also want to use strings instead of characters so I enter a sequence of strings separated by a "," and store them in a map similar to the one mentioned above. I would appreciate any help !

Comment: As a beginner, I cannot recommend Spirit parsers, and certainly [not with semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Phoenix place holders outside Phoenix deferred actors. E.g. the type of `std::make_pair(qi::_1, 0)` is `std::pair<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<0>>, int>`.

Nothing interoperates with such a thing. Certainly not [`std::map<>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

What you'd need to do is wrap all the operations in semantic actions as Phoenix actors.

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
namespace px = boost::phoenix;
```

Then you can:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace myparser {
    using Map = std::map<char, int>;

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
        auto action = px::insert(px::ref(m), px::end(px::ref(m)),
                                 px::construct<std::pair<char, int>>(qi::_1, 0));

        bool r = qi::phrase_parse( //
            first, last,
            //  Begin grammar
            qi::char_[action] >> *(',' >> qi::char_[action]),
            //  End grammar
            qi::space);

        return r && first == last;
    }
} // namespace myparser
```

See it **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4dc583c2706023)**

Easy peasy. Right.

I spent half an hour on that thing debugging why it wouldn't work. Why is this so hard?

It's because someone invented a whole meta-DSL to write "normal C++" but with defferred execution. Back when that happened it was pretty neat, but it is the mother of all leaky abstractions, with razor sharp edges.

So, what's new? Using C++11 you could:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9956cfe340014df)**

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
    struct action_f {
        Map& m_;
        void operator()(char ch) const { m_.emplace(ch, 0); }
    };
    px::function<action_f> action{{m}};

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse( //
        first, last,
        //  Begin grammar
        qi::char_[action(qi::_1)] >> *(',' >> qi::char_[action(qi::_1)]),
        //  End grammar
        qi::space);

    return r && first == last;
}
```

Or using c++17:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19e2d52177cb2033)**

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
    px::function action{[&m](char ch) { m.emplace(ch, 0); }};

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse( //
        first, last,
        //  Begin grammar
        qi::char_[action(qi::_1)] >> *(',' >> qi::char_[action(qi::_1)]),
        //  End grammar
        qi::space);

    return r && first == last;
}
```

On a tangent, you probably wanted to **count** things, so, maybe use

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56ece0b96a78eb43)**

```
px::function action{[&m](char ch) { m[ch] += 1; }};
```

By this time, you could switch to Spirit X3 (which requires C++14):

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9daade875bc62235)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace myparser {
    using Map = std::map<char, int>;

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
        auto action = [&m](auto& ctx) { m[_attr(ctx)] += 1; };

        return x3::phrase_parse( //
                first, last,
                //  Begin grammar
                x3::char_[action] >> *(',' >> x3::char_[action]) >> x3::eoi,
                //  End grammar
                x3::space);
    }
} // namespace myparser
```

Now finally, let's simplify. `p >> *(',' >> p)` is just a clumsy way of saying `p % ','`:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d66879312500214)**

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
    auto action = [&m](auto& ctx) { m[_attr(ctx)] += 1; };

    return x3::phrase_parse(     //
        first, last,             //
        x3::char_[action] % ',', //
        x3::space);
}
```

And you wanted words, not characters:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3140508d60cbd6e8)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace myparser {
    using Map = std::map<std::string, int>;

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, Map& m) {
        auto action = [&m](auto& ctx) { m[_attr(ctx)] += 1; };

        auto word_ = (*~x3::char_(','))[action];

        return phrase_parse(first, last, word_ % ',', x3::space);
    }
} // namespace myparser

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (std::string const str : {"foo,c++ is strange,bar,qux,foo,c++       is strange   ,cuz"}) {
        std::map<std::string, int> m;

        std::cout << "Parsing " << std::quoted(str) << std::endl;

        if (myparser::parse_numbers(str.begin(), str.end(), m)) {
            std::cout << m.size() << " words:\n";
            for (auto& [word,count]: m)
                std::cout << " - " << std::quoted(word) << " :: " << count << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Parsing failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsing "foo,c++ is strange,bar,qux,foo,c++       is strange   ,cuz"
5 words:
 - "bar" :: 1
 - "c++isstrange" :: 2
 - "cuz" :: 1
 - "foo" :: 2
 - "qux" :: 1
```

Note the behaviour of the `x3::space` (like `qi::space` and `qi::ascii::space` above).

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough, rich explanation ! I really appreciate it.